# Why does only IE check the X-Frame-Options Header when iFrame src sends a file?

Tags: google-chrome, http, internet-explorer, firefox, http-headers

Debugging a strange problem, I stumbled across an interesting behaviour:

On a web page, I trigger a file download with the following JavaScript code:

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.src = 'download.php';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

The PHP script download.php sends a text file with the X-Frame-Options header set to DENY:

```
<?php 
   header('X-Frame-Options: DENY');
   header('Content-type: text/plain');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="text.txt"');
?>
Text
```

Chrome and Firefox allow the file download, IE 11 shows an iframe with a message saying the content can't be embedded.

What is the correct behaviour? To me, it makes much more sense what IE does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`X-Frame-Options` exists to prevent click-jacking. Preventing a file from being downloaded is not something that `X-Frame-Options` aims to achieve, since such a restriction can easily be bypassed by opening a link in a new window.

Therefore the behavior of Chrome and Firefox is correct.

<sub>(See also https://crbug.com/331211 "The X-Frame-Options flags aren't intended to prevent downloading. They only prevent displaying the page as a subframe.")</sub>